# Apache bench becomes slow with high concurrent user

Tags: apache

My apache seems getting slow when concurrent user is about 55
When I made this request:
ab -c55 -n1000 "http://office.zensis.com:7999/test"
I get this result:
Requests per second:    50.74 [#/sec] (mean)

A value like 45 or 65 is slower than that of 55
Does that means I can only achieve the best performance when concurrent user is about 55?
But I can see the cpu loading is below 10%.
Besides, my server config is like this:
Intel Xero 2.40 Ghz
8Gb ram